# Using LaTeX to generate .png images of an equation

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, png

I am familiar with using LaTeX on online websites (like MathOverflow or Physicsforums).  My input is rendered using MathJax.  However, I do not understand the LaTeX environment in its native OS form.  I have downloaded MacTeX, and all I would like to do is make tiny little .png or .jpg files that each contain one equation.

After some Googling, I have tried something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} = 0.5
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

followed by

```
pdflatex equation.tex
convert -density 300 equation.pdf -quality 95 equation.png
```

(using ImageMagick's `convert` program), but the output contains a number next to my equation that I can't seem to get rid of.  Also, this seems like a lot of work, and I don't need a whole `documentclass` just for one equation.  Not to mention `pdflatex` produces a bunch of other auxiliary files that clutter up my directory during the conversion process.  Is there some way I can just easily go from a file containing

```
\frac{1}{2} = 0.5
```

to `equation.png`?  Better yet, is there a simple way I can take a file containing a list of equations and have each of them converted into their own little .png image?

Comment: replace the equation env with `\[`and `\]`

Comment: Thanks!  That helps a lot.  Is there also a way to shrinkwrap the generated pdf around the equation?  I have huge margins consisting only of whitespace.

Comment: You could use the geometry package to reduce the size of the page with `\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=1.5in]{geometry}`. It might be better done at the `convert` stage, though, with the `-trim` option, which strips all pixels from the outside edges which match the corner pixels in color.

Comment: I would use a simple math group `$ a+b$`, or *if* needed the diplayed mode: `$\sum_{0}^{k}$`.

Answer (score 26):

`standalone` class is sufficient. You can enable the `multi` option, so that the contents of each (math) environment is cropped to its own page in a PDF file. Then you can either save each page directly as a `.png` image (Acrobat Pro, and perhaps Adobe Reader, allows you to do it in one go), or you can use the `convert` functionality (need Image Magick) provided with `standalone`. For the latter method, see Section 4.6 of [the `standalone` documentation](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf).

In the example below I define a new environment `mymath`, which is basically inline math with display style.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[multi={mymath},border=1pt]{standalone}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{mymath}{$\displaystyle}{$}

\begin{document}

\begin{mymath}
  \frac{1}{2}=0.5
\end{mymath}

\begin{mymath}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{mymath}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: The standalone using convert route would look something like: `\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=800x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}` in case anybody wants a quick example.

Comment: Probably section 5.6 in manual now?

Comment: Minor addition: I needed to set `varwidth=true` to get rid of some unnecessary horizontal space.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I do to go from a file of equations to png files using `asymptote`.  You'll need the following 3 files in a directory.

sample.bat - change the "5" to alter the png resolution

```
asy sample -noV -render 5 -f png
pause
```

sample.dat - this file holds your equations.

```
\frac{1}{2} = 0.5
y = \sin{x}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

sample.asy - this is the asymptote code

```
file fin = input("sample.dat").line();
int index = 1;
while (!eof(fin))
{
    string s = fin;
    if (s == "") { continue; }
    label("$\displaystyle " + s + "$", (0,0));
    shipout("eq"+string(index));
    erase();
    ++index;
}
```

Running the batch file will create the following 3 png files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Since you have MacTeX, use [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/), which lets you convert equations to images in several formats, including PDF and PNG. There is no need to write LaTeX support code: just enter the equation in the input box and press "LaTeX it!".

If you want to convert equations in batch, you can write a simple script that adds the equation to a template based on the `standalone` class, runs `latex`, and then `dvipng`.

There are also web services, such as [Roger's Online Equation Editor](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php).

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be that latex automatically numbers equations in the equation environment. This default behavior of latex's is likely because authors often need to refer to equations. An easy solution is to remove numbering by using

```
\begin{equation*}
YOUR EQUATION GOES HERE
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am missing the reputation to add a comment to Herr K.'s answer...

In order to generate individual PNG files on **Windows**, you may need to specify the actual `convert` executable on your path (`standalone` assumes this to be `imgconvert` on Windows, instead of `convert`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  multi={mymath},
  border=2pt,
  convert={convertexe={convert},density=300,outext=.png}
  ]{standalone}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{mymath}{$\displaystyle}{$}

\begin{document}

\begin{mymath}
  \frac{1}{2}=0.5
\end{mymath}

\begin{mymath}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{mymath}

\end{document}
```

This generates to following two PNG files:

[image: 1st example]

[image: 2nd example]

Answer (score 2):

I want to add my two cents here. I wasn't satisfied with the current solutions so I wrote a script. You can find it here, [pnglatex](https://github.com/mneri/pnglatex). In its simplest form you can use it like this:

```
pnglatex -f '\frac{1}{2}'
```

To get a full list of options use `pnglatex -h`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DMelt (http://jwork.org/dmelt) version 2 and above, you can make PNG file from equation using Python syntax:

```
from jhplot import *
eq="\\frac{\sin(x*2)}{\int^{100}_{i=0} F(x) dx}"
image="/tmp/equation.png" # output file
# create equation 
q1=HLatexEq(eq, 64)       # font size 64 
q1.export(image)
print "Created :",image
IView(image)              # View this image
```

Comment: Does this use LaTeX as a backend or some fake MathJax?

Comment: I wonder whether this answer is useful at all.  Google cannot even find `HLatexEq`: https://www.google.com/search?q="HLatexEq"